# cannot subscribe to onedrive API

Tags: onedrive

I tried to subscribe to onedrive webhooks by hitting
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions

parameters are:

```
"changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
             "notificationUrl": url.
               "resource": "me/drive/root",
               "clientState": "client-specific string",
            "expirationDateTime": "2018-01-01T11:23:00.000Z",
```

I am getting an error like below:

```
 { error:
   { code: 'InvalidRequest',
     message: 'Server could not process subscription creation payload.',
     innerError:
      { 'request-id': 'id',
        date: '2018-10-16T09:16:46' } } }
```

I am trying it in my local.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you post a json request, that means:

1. Request body is a json string;
2. 'Content-Type' field in headers, and value is 'application/json'

If you use Python, there is a shortcut:

```py
import requests
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "YOUR_TOKEN"}
data = {
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationUrl": url.
    "resource": "me/drive/root",
    "clientState": "client-specific string",
    "expirationDateTime": "2018-01-01T11:23:00.000Z"
}
resp = requests.post(headers=headers, json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying the request with Postman. The body was in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format. It worked when I changed the body format to `raw` and specified `JSON`.

[Not working "x-www-form-urlencoded" format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNXXN.png)

[Working "raw" format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN5TJ.png)

It looks like MS Graph API only accepts certain input formats. Hope this will help!